# Understanding how model resolution works

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. Managed to get some apps running, but I have some doubts on how things work in some direction, and can't find the explanation I am looking for. Particularly in this method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }

}
```

I know `"Hello Spring MVC Framework!"` (under name `message`) is being passed to the view. But there are two things that concern me and find slightly unusual:

1. Why is the `model` declared as *input* parameter to the `printHello` method? and not say as local variable?
2. `model` is nowhere being passed to the view *explicitly*, so does this happen behind the scenes somehow?

Comment: I'm thinking like this when DispatcherServlet consults the HandlerMapping to call the appropriate Controller, perhaps it contructs it's own ModelMap object so that it passess the object to method's argument. And if you explicity construct it via local instantiation then the object is not managed by the handler hence no binding happens. So can just consider it as convention/agreement, something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the `model` declared as input parameter to the `printHello` method? and not say as local variable?

You can declare it as local variable and return it if you want:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelMap printHello() {
    return new ModelMap("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
}
```

But this way you are not take advantage of Spring's data binding (binding request attributes (query parameters for GET request) to model).

Also this way you not providing any view name (as in your original example `return "hello"`), so Spring MVC will deduce it using default `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator` which uses controller name without `Controller` suffix as logical view name (in your example it will be `hello` because your controller is `HelloController`). See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-coc-r2vnt) for more info.

Also you can return new `ModelAndView` instance instead of just `Model` or `ModelMap`. In this case you can explicitly set view name and model attributes.

**But main advantage of using Model as handler method argument is data binding.**

When you provide Model **and** some model attribute (to bind request to) as method arguments, then you get model instance with already added (and filled using request params) model attribute to your model and then you can add another attributes to it if you need it.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(Model model, @ModelAttribute("form") SearchForm form, BindingResult result) {
    model.addAttribute("anotherUsefulValue", myService.getSomeValue());
    // 'hello' view will get the model with both 'form' and 'anotherUsefulValue' attributes
    // and 'form' attribute will have 'text' field filled from request's
    // query parameter 'text'.
    return "hello";
}

class SearchForm {
    private String text;
    // ... getter and setter
}
```

Using this method, you can do GET request from some html `form` with text field named `text` and when you submit this form, your model will contain attribute `form` with instantiated `SearchForm` object as value. And field `text` of this object will have `text` query parameter as value.

Example using [spring-form JSP Tag Library](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.select):

```
<form:form method="GET" action="/hello" modelAttribute="form">
    <form:input path="text" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or just enter URL `/hello?text=12345`. And you will see that `model` will have `form` attribute with `text` field equal to `12345` **and** it also have your `anotherUsefulValue` attribute. You just combined Spring's data binding with your custom model attributes.

Of course you can create new model manually and set your `anotherUsefulValue` along with `form` attribute from method's `form` argument. But it is just more boilerplate.

> `model` is nowhere being passed to the view *explicitly*, so does this happen behind the scenes somehow?

Of course. Spring's `DispatcherServlet` do this for you as many other things. This all described in [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet).

[image: The request processing workflow in Spring Web MVC (high level)]

The `Front Controller` just know what your controller method returned and can understand if it is new model or your method not returned any model and then `Front Controller` uses model which it passed to your controller method as argument.

Answer (score 1):

The `@RequestMapping` annotation you've provided does this *magically*. I say that in both a literal and metaphorical sense. It basically cuts out the mess hand-wiring everything would typically involve.

1. The model is one of *many* optional input parameters. You could, if you wanted to, provide more, or less, or none. In this case, you want to use the ModalMap, so you say, "I want to use a ModalMap" by including the argument. If you have arguments coming from the request, such as in the header, you can add those in and cast to them.
2. This is similar to `@Autowire` by Spring. When you autowire a service, you never explicitly say `new FooService()` anywhere, but it is automatically created and managed for you by Spring. You're basically offloading most of the wiring work to Spring, and it handles all the boilerplate while you handle exactly what you need it to handle.

In this case, you're passing a ModalMap with a value to the client from a get request, and then the value is loaded on the page.

Additional Reading + Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Comment: my point was: (1) it was weird for me to see model as input parameter and (2) I can't see is explicitly being passed to the view. PS. Also in this case, the only text displayed on the view is the one I presented in code, so I assume no other data is received e.g. with GET.

Comment: Regarding #2, it's akin to this. `Foo foo = new Foo(); String s = doSomething(foo);` Spring still has the reference to `foo` in this case. It doesn't need to `foo` returned as well up to where it helps the page to load. Since it's the only `GET` method mapped, and has no args you could call the method whatever you wanted and it would still be the target method for a response.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `model` object passed as an argument, similar to `HttpServletRequest` object I added below in your code. Spring generates an implicit model object that is available throughout a request lifecycle, similar to implicit `request` object that is available to a JSP. So, per single request lifecycle, this implicit model object will be shared across controller and view.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }

}
```

Below is the description from [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html). where it is mentioned what is the significance of input params that are passed to methods annotated with @RequestMapping

> Map / Model / ModelMap for enriching the implicit model that will be
>   exposed to the web view.

Answer (score 0):

A **new** `model` object created by Spring-MVC framework for every request.That is why it's not a local variable. Since the object itself created by the framework it already has a reference too it so framework takes care of passing it to the View.